# rails - comparison of arrays of sentences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two arrays of sentences As you can see I'm trying to match applicant abilities with job requirements.

```
Array A
-Must be able to use MS Office
-Applicant should be prepared to work 40 to 50 hours a week
-Must know FDA Regulations, FCC Regulations
-Must be willing to work in groups

Array B
-Proficient in MS Office
-Experience with FDA Regulations
-Willing to work long hours
-Has experience with math applications.
```

Is there any way to compare the two arrays and determine how many similarities there are? Preferably on a sentence by sentence basis (not just picking out words that are similar) returning a percentage similar.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what are you looking for when you say "similar"? Are there particular key phrases that you are focusing on?  Would something like the way cucumber uses regular expressions to parse scenarios work?

Comment: Hm I'm not exactly sure. I guess when I say similar..pick like sentence 3 of Array A and sentence 2 of Array B should show a partial match because of 'FDA regulations.' I'm trying to get an overall percentage of how the applicants listed abilities match with the job requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is pretty difficult and it is the buzz of natural language processing today.

[NLTK](http://nltk.org) is the toolkit of choice, but it's in python. There are lots of academic papers in this field. Most use [copuses to train a a model](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=1644735)  where the hypothesis is that words that are similar tend to be in similar contexts (i.e. surrounded by similar words). This is very computationally expensive.

You can come up with a rudimentary solution by using the the nltk library with this plan in mind:

- Remove filler words (a, the, and)
- Use the part of speech tagger to identify label verbs, nouns etc (I'd
  remove anything else than nouns and verbs)
- For, say any twos noun (verbs), use the wordnet library to get
  synonyms of that word. And if you have a match you count. There are
  lots of other papers on this that use corpuses to build lexicons
  which can use word frequencies to measure word similarities. The
  latter method is preferred because you are likely to relate words
  that are similar but do not have synonyms in common.
- You can then give a relative measure of sentence similarity based on the word similarity

Other methods consider the syntactic structure of sentence, but you don't get that much benefits from this. Unfortunately, the above method is not very good, because of the nature of wordnet.